# Yahoo Pipes says source page is too long

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I want to use Yahoo pipes to extract part of a webpage and convert it to RSS. The problem is Pipes says the page is too long which is frustrating, because seemingly I can't do anything about it.

Is there a way to solve this problem within Pipes?

If not, the only way I can think of is finding a web service similar to Pipes which can extract a part of a page and use its output as an input for Pipes. Do you know such a service?

Answer (score 0):

On this page from Google you can shrink webpages for browsing with mobile phones:
http://www.google.com/gwt/n

It reduces the size of the page a lot, so maybe it helps you.

Comment: Great thought, but unfortunately the Pipes "Fetch Page" module doesn't allow you to get pages that are disallowed by robots.txt, and the results of the gwt tool are marked no-index.